# paraphrase "tunnels beneath glacially formed sandy ridges"

Tags: sentence-structure

> Prairie potholes were formed during the most recent Ice Age, when streams flowed in tunnels beneath glacially formed sandy ridges.

I am confused by "tunnels beneath glacially formed sandy ridges". Which formed which?

Answer (score 3):

*Glacially formed* (which could also be written *glacially-formed*) is an adjectival phrase that describes 'sandy ridges'. The text you quoted means that sandy ridges were (previously) formed by glaciers, and the streams flowed in tunnels beneath these ridges.

Answer (score 0):

You can rephrase as follows:

> ...when streams flowed  in tunnels  beneath sandy ridges which formed during the glacial era.